# How can i sort individual json like objects in a file based on one key

Tags: python, json

I have series of values like this in a file.

```
{
  "canceled": false,
  "complete_time": "2017-06-08T15:55:45.616942",
  "create_time": "2017-06-08T15:55:44.370344",
  "entity_list": [
    {
      "entity_type": 2,
      "uuid": "xxxxx"
    },
    {
      "entity_name": "",
      "uuid": "xxxx"
    }
  ],
  "last_updated_time": "2017-06-08T15:55:45.616942",
  "progress_status": 3,
  "request": {
    "arg": {
      "parent_task_uuid": "xxx",
      "task_uuid": "xxxx",
      "transition": 2,
      "vm_uuid": "xxx"
    },
    "method_name": """""
  },
  "response": {
    "error_code": 0,
    "error_detail": "",
    "ret": {}
  },
  "start_time": "2017-06-08T15:55:44.452703",
  "uuid": "xxxxx"
}
{
  "canceled": false,
  "complete_time": "2017-06-08T15:55:45.616942",
  "create_time": "2017-06-08T15:55:44.370344",
  "entity_list": [
    {
      "entity_type": 2,
      "uuid": "xxxxx"
    },
    {
      "entity_name": "",
      "uuid": "xxxx"
    }
  ],
  "last_updated_time": "2017-06-08T15:55:45.616942",
  "progress_status": 3,
  "request": {
    "arg": {
      "parent_task_uuid": "xxx",
      "task_uuid": "xxxx",
      "transition": 2,
      "vm_uuid": "xxx"
    },
    "method_name": """""
  },
  "response": {
    "error_code": 0,
    "error_detail": "",
    "ret": {}
  },
  "start_time": "2017-06-08T15:55:44.452703",
  "uuid": "xxxxx"
}
```

I want to sort these individual chunks {} based on the 'last_updated_field'. If its like a JSON, i have written the code to work in Python but since this is not a valid JSON, how can i make this work.

```
while True:
line = sys.stdin.readline()
if not line: break
line = line.strip()
json_obj = json.loads(line)
lines.append(json_obj)

lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda k: k['last_updated_time'], reverse=True)
```

Comment: You have it in your file like this? Without commas between the objects and brackets around the list?

Comment: Yes. no commas between the objects and brackets.

Comment: The *only* positive thing about this horribile format is that JSON does not allow  the combination `}{` outside of strings and you might be able to get proper JSON by adding the brackets and doing a regual expression replace `}\s*{` → `}, {`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your problem is not exactly sorting these objects, your last line should  work just fine. The issue is how to read the slightly malformed json file. This is kind of hacky way to digest your file. You may google for a json package that has better toleration for format deviation.

```
import json
chunks = list()
temp_lines = list()
fp = open(FILE_PATH)
for line in fp:
    line = line.replace(r'"""""', r'"\""')
    temp_lines.append(line)
    if line.startswith('}'):
        chunks.append(json.loads(''.join(temp_lines)))
        temp_lines.clear()
chunks = sorted(chunks, key=lambda x: x['last_updated_time'], reverse=True)
```

To get back to your original horrible format, add these two lines

```
chunks = '\n'.join([json.dumps(x, indent=4) for x in chunks])
chunks = chunks.replace(r'"\""', r'"""""')
```

Comment: thanks, this works fine, but it doesn't preserve the structure. It prints something like
{u'internal_task': False, u'parent_task_uuid': u'xxx', u'progress_status': 3, u'complete_time': u'2017-05-23T19:01:54.914895', u'entity_list': [{u'uuid': u'xxxx', u'entity_name': u'UM-EX', u'entity_type': 2}, {u'uuid': u'cbb4a1fa-f393-4878-a7d3-41bf3f519b3b', u'entity_name': u'xxx', u'entity_type': 1}]...}
I want to preserve the same structure as in the file but just sort the whole chunk {}.

Comment: Why in hell would you want to preserve such a horrible format? Be thankful that you can get this into a semi-sane data format and output some actual json from that.

Anyway, see my edit on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try accumulating lines until you form a valid json. Put all these jsons in a list, then sort it like you know how to e.g. something like

```
import sys
all_jsons = []
current_lines = []
counter = 0
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    line = line.strip()
    current_lines.append(line)
    nb_inc = line.count("{")
    nb_dec = line.count("}")
    counter += nb_inc
    counter -= nb_dec
    if counter == 0:
        # We have met as many opening bracket as closing, this is a full json
        all_jsons.append("\n".join(current_lines))
        current_lines = []

# sort your json files
```

Here I accumulate lines until I have encountered as many closing bracket as opening. In which case I join all the lines into one json formatted string.